# String Class: Create new Method, which returns a qlDate

Tags: c#, string, date, quantlib

Here I have a Example Code. My goal is to Create a Method which returns a `ql.Date` from a `String`. Is it possible? I set the Date String from Excel. But the Application needs to get a `ql.Date()`. Now I wrote for any Date a return method. Which is quite inelegant.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.Date1 = "08/04/2023";
        myClass.Date2 = "05/25/2012";
        // get would return a String, but I need the Date. 
        // So I call the method to get the Date:
        QuantLib.Date qlDate1 = myClass.returnQLDate1();
        QuantLib.Date qlDate2 = myClass.returnQLDate2();
        //My goal is a general method for all Dates (Date1, Date2, Date3,...) 
        // like this:
        QuantLib.Date qlDateX = myClass.DateX.toQLDate();
    }
}
```

MyClass:

```
public class MyClass
{
    string _Date1, _Date2; //string _Date3,...Date6,...double _rate, _cpn;
    public string Date1
    {
        private get { return _Date1; }
        set { _Date1 = value; }
    }

    public string Date2
    {
        private get { return _Date2; }
        set { _Date2 = value; }
    }

    public QuantLib.Date returnQLDate1()
    { return new QuantLib.Date(Date1, "mm/dd/yyyy"); }
    public QuantLib.Date returnQLDate2()
    { return new QuantLib.Date(Date2, "mm/dd/yyyy"); }
    //  public QuantLib.Date returnQLDate3()
    //  { return....       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) (of course, name is arguable)

```
public static QuantLib.Date ToQuantLibDate(this string value)
{
    return new QuantLib.Date(value, "mm/dd/yyyy"); }
}
```

Usage:

```
var str = "08/04/2023";
var date = str.ToQuantLibDate();
```

Comment: Many thanks! But it only worked in a new "public static class Ext". Is their any possibility to put it in the "public class myClass"

Comment: @user3924697 no, extension methods should be defined only in static classes. Just create some class `QuantLibExtensions`